# Linking error in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm just putting the finishing touches on a project I've been working on to render a scene in OpenGL - I based some of it on some old code I wrote for a Camera class (since I didn't want to have to re-figure out the maths!), however I'd included the Camera class as part of main.cpp before, and I wanted to move it to it's own seperate .h/.cpp files for the sake of reusability/clarity/general good practice.

I also replaced a basic Struct to hold the x and y position of the mouse with a Mouse class that I wrote.

I changed some code in the Windows Message Handler to have the Camera update when the Left Mouse Button is released - however I am getting a strange linking error -

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol "public: void
>   __thiscall Camera::moveCamera(int,int,int,int)"
>   (?moveCamera@Camera@@QAEXHHHH@Z)

The code in the Windows Message Handler is -

```
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        Mouse.SetPos(lParam); 
        x_mouse_end = Mouse.GetXPos();
        y_mouse_end = Mouse.GetYPos(); 
        Camera.moveCamera(x_mouse_start, y_mouse_start, x_mouse_end, y_mouse_end);
        SetCamera(); 
        break;
```

The parameters I'm passing to Camera.moveCamera() are integers as they are supposed to be.

The moveCamera() function is as follows -

```
//Moves the camera based on a user dragging the mouse 
inline void Camera::moveCamera(int old_x, int old_y, int new_x, int new_y)
{
    //To store the differences between the old and new mouse positions 
    int x_difference, y_difference; 

    //If the mouse was dragged to the right, move the camera right
    if(new_x > old_x)
    {
        x_difference = new_x - old_x;
        x_difference = x_difference / 25;

        if(yaw > 350)
        {
            yaw = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            yaw = yaw + x_difference;
        }
    }

    //If the mouse was dragged to the left, move the camera left
    if(new_x < old_x)
    {
        x_difference = old_x - new_x;
        x_difference = x_difference / 25;

        if(yaw < 10)
        {
            yaw = 360;
        }
        else
        {
            yaw = yaw - x_difference;
        }
    }

    //If the mouse was dragged down, move the camera down
    if(new_y < old_y)
    {
        y_difference = new_y - old_y;
        y_difference = y_difference / 20;

        if(pitch < 10)
        {
            pitch = 360;
        }
        else
        {
            pitch = pitch - y_difference;
        }
    }

    //If the mouse was dragged up, move the camera up
    if(new_y > old_y)
    {
        y_difference = old_y - new_y;
        y_difference = y_difference / 20;
        if(pitch > 350)
        {
            pitch = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            pitch = pitch + y_difference;
        }
    }

    //Update the camera position based on the new Yaw, Pitch and Roll
    cameraUpdate();

}
```

"camera.h" is included as it should be, as is "mouse.h", and instances of both classes are set up -

```
Mouse Mouse;
Camera Camera;
```

I'm at a loss as to what could be missing.

Please let me know if you would like more information.

Comment: Is moveCamera in a different  dll  or project ?

Comment: No it's in the Camera class which is in camera.h - Diego has found the issue however - thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you included that definition of `moveCamera()` in a .cpp file with the "`inline`" keyword. This may be interpreted that this method is local to the .cpp in which it is defined. Try removing the `inline`.

Comment: I thought inline meant for the compiler to try to do something in one go? (Sorry if that's a naive perception)

Comment: inline is usually used when you want to inline a method definition that you include in the same .h file, but outside the class definition. Otherwise usually means "static", as the compiler will try to inline as much as possible most of the time (with optimizations enabled, that is).

Comment: @ShimmerGeek - It is, but it also makes the function local to the file. And lets you have inlined copies in several files.

Comment: for compiler to inline a function it must see its definition. It will not work if it is in a different .cpp file. So alternatively you could move the definition of the inlined moveCamera to the header file.

Comment: Ah thank you! I'll look into it some more so I'm clear - good to know :)

Comment: If you want it to be inline to an outside file, you need to write the implementation in the .h file. That way the other files can see the implementation with the include.